# Resolution gap between normal wordpress menu and mobile menu

Tags: php, css, wordpress, menu, responsive-design

I'm experiencing a weird problem in my website that I haven't been able to solve myself so far: My site [www.20watt.nl](http://www.20watt.nl) displays the normal navigation menu in all resolutions *above* 958 pixels, while my plugin "wp responsive menu" takes over for resolutions below 768. But *between* a resolution of 768-958, my site shows no menu at all (can be tested easily using screenfly)

My question: Where / how do I specify the resolution where my mobile menu takes over / i.e. becomes responsive? I've changed it in the plugin-settings, but that does not seem to help.

I'd like to have my mobile menu take over exactly at 958 pixels (because that's where the "normal" menu seems to end)

Many thanks & regards,

Answer (score 1):

In your stylesheet `responsive.css` (http://www.20watt.nl/wp-content/themes/Foliowhite/css/responsive.css), the following line is hiding your menu:

```
#site-navigation ul { display: none; }
```

You will want to remove that from the `max-width:959px` media query block and add it to the `max-width:767px` block.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - changed it around, ands while it now does display the normal nav menu until the mobile menu takes over, now the layout goes wrong. The nav menu overlaps the slider between the 958 and 768 resolutions. Ideally I'd like to keep the nav menu hidden from 958 downwards and show the mobile menu instead.  Thanks for your help and in the meantime I'll keep trying to edit responsive.css to see if I can fix it (so far no luck)

Comment: Yeah, if there's not a setting in the plugin to change its behavior (ie, what width it becomes active at), you're likely going to have to make a lot of changes and maybe even `!important` declarations to override its behavior. And, as you update the plugin down the road, this can lead to additional headaches, FWIW.